# Data preparation for multi-label text classification in deep learning

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, recurrent-neural-network, text-classification, data-preprocessing

I am trying to create a deep learning model that scans menu. In particular, it can categorize a block of text into dish name, dish price, or dish description, etc.

Based on my basic knowledge of deep learning, the bag-of-word strategy usually can be used for problems involving texts as it converts each word into a one-hot vector. However, in my case, it seems that the model is required to analyze features beyond simply the occurrences of each word. For example, dish prices may usually consist of numbers, dish descriptions are usually longer than dish names in lengths, etc.

What are some possible approaches I can use in the text preprocessing so that I can create vector inputs that are more effective for this particular task? Also, what are some models that may perform better for this task?

Answer (score 0):

Tasks looks like a typical token-classification (NER-like) task. Consider using the LayoutLM family if you have a an image of the menu, embedding will consider both textual input and visual input to create high-quality document representations that can then be fed into various heads. You would leverage large pre-training with availabe open-source models.

https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/layoutlmv3